# OSX Java upgrade doesn't reflect command line -version. Why?

Tags: java, version

I upgraded java on my osx 10.9.4 machine using the suggested method from the [java web site](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_java_update.xml)

It successfully updated, but when trying to run Eclipse I get an error:

```
Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product.  
Version 1.7 or greater is required.
```

When I access java settings through the applet in the control panel, it shows Java 7 Update 65, but when I type java -version in the console, it shows 1.6.0_65 (response shown below):

```
| => java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-466.1-11M4716)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-466.1, mixed mode)
```

As far as I know, there is only one java on the box.  "which java" returns /usr/bin/java and type -a java returns only /usr/bin/java also.   /usr/bin/java is obviously the older version, but I'd like to use the updated one.  Can someone please tell me how to update the /usr/bin/java version and/or how to link the applet version so that Eclipse will use the updated one?

Comment: I think /usr/bin/java is a link to the /Library... java path. Try setting up the link to new jdk7

Comment: Not sure where the new jdk7 is located.  How would one locate it it was updated by the applet?

Comment: Update:  I found this under the Java Control Panel applet.  
1.7 1.7.0_65 http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java 

So link /usr/bin/java to this java?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at oracle documentation here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html

It says:

> To run a different version of Java, either specify the full path, or
>   use the java_home tool:
>
> ```
> /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7.0_06 --exec javac -version
> ```

The `/usr/libexec/java_home` is a link to your jdk directory that should be located under:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<major>.<minor>.<macro[_update]>.jdk
```

I think your **java_home** link is pointing to your jdk6. You can check it doing a `ls -l /usr/libexec/`